Why is RTL8188EE wifi dropping networks, then disconnecting?
A few weeks after upgrading from Debian 11 to 12 (which could be purely coincidental), my 10-year old HP laptop's RTL8188EE wireless connection would slow down, the number of available networks would gradually decrease from 20 or so to none (my home network being among the last to go), and finally it would disconnect. None of the usual "ip link" commands I tried would bring the interface back up. This happened once every few days, then several times a day, and then too frequently to be usable. A reboot would bring it to life again for a few minutes, but eventually the interface would be down upon boot and would stay down on subsequent boots. This whole cycle took a week or two.
If I reinstalled Debian or any other Linux distribution (AntiX, Archcraft, Manjaro, Spiral) the interface would behave normally at first, then same cycle would occur. Same if I ran a distribution from ISO via Ventoy.
I strongly suspect the problem is related to TX power, but I'm in over my head trying to troubleshoot this.
Things I've tried:

Upgrading BIOS. Not saying much as the most recent is 2018 (up from 2014)
Disabling MAC address randomization
Trying different networks at friends' houses
Archcraft and Spiral used a much more recentkernel than Debian, but same behavior

I am using IW for wireless management; NetworkManager.service and wpa_supplicant.service are permanently disabled. IW works great until the above occurs.
I appreciate any guidance! Thanks!
$ dmesg -T | grep 'rtl\|wlan'

[Wed Aug  7 17:20:47 2024] rtl8188ee: rtl8188ee: FW Power Save off (module option)
[Wed Aug  7 17:20:47 2024] rtl8188ee: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
[Wed Aug  7 17:20:47 2024] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[Wed Aug  7 17:20:47 2024] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[Wed Aug  7 17:20:47 2024] rtl8188ee 0000:08:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
[Wed Aug  7 17:20:51 2024] r8169 0000:09:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_nic/rtl8106e-2.fw
[Wed Aug  7 22:02:29 2024] wlan0: authenticate with cc:ab:2c:5c:6d:e4
[Wed Aug  7 22:02:29 2024] wlan0: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
[Wed Aug  7 22:02:29 2024] wlan0: send auth to cc:ab:2c:5c:6d:e4 (try 1/3)
[Wed Aug  7 22:02:29 2024] wlan0: authenticated
[Wed Aug  7 22:02:29 2024] wlan0: associate with cc:ab:2c:5c:6d:e4 (try 1/3)
[Wed Aug  7 22:02:29 2024] wlan0: RX AssocResp from cc:ab:2c:5c:6d:e4 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=18)
[Wed Aug  7 22:02:29 2024] wlan0: associated
[Wed Aug  7 22:02:29 2024] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by cc:ab:2c:5c:6d:e4
[Wed Aug  7 22:02:29 2024] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[Thu Aug  8 01:23:42 2024] rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now
[Thu Aug  8 01:23:42 2024] wlan0: Connection to AP cc:ab:2c:5c:6d:e4 lost
[Thu Aug  8 01:23:44 2024] wlan0: authenticate with cc:ab:2c:5c:6d:e4
[Thu Aug  8 01:23:44 2024] wlan0: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
[Thu Aug  8 01:23:44 2024] wlan0: send auth to cc:ab:2c:5c:6d:e4 (try 1/3)
[Thu Aug  8 01:23:44 2024] wlan0: authenticated
[Thu Aug  8 01:23:44 2024] wlan0: associate with cc:ab:2c:5c:6d:e4 (try 1/3)
[Thu Aug  8 01:23:44 2024] wlan0: RX AssocResp from cc:ab:2c:5c:6d:e4 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=20)
[Thu Aug  8 01:23:44 2024] wlan0: associated
[Thu Aug  8 01:23:44 2024] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by cc:ab:2c:5c:6d:e4
[Thu Aug  8 06:50:08 2024] rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now
[Thu Aug  8 06:50:08 2024] wlan0: Connection to AP cc:ab:2c:5c:6d:e4 lost

$ inxi -MJN
    
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP Pavilion 17 Notebook PC
  Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 227F v: 77.35
    UEFI: Insyde v: F.57 date: 11/09/2018
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter driver: rtl8188ee
  Device-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet driver: r8169

$ iwconfig wlan0

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          
$ lshw -C network

  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: c0:38:96:82:c6:9e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=6.1.0-22-amd64 firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:50 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2500000-b2503fff

$ lspci -nnkvvv

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE mini-PCIe card [103c:197d]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 50
    Region 0: I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at b2500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee01004  Data: 0025
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <128ns, L1 <2us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset- SlotPowerLimit 10W
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ NonFatalErr- FatalErr+ UnsupReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L0s L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR+
             10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Via message/WAKE#, ExtFmt- EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS- TPHComp- ExtTPHComp-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis+ LTR+ 10BitTagReq- OBFF Disabled,
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkCap2: Supported Link Speeds: 2.5GT/s, Crosslink- Retimer- 2Retimers- DRS-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance Preset/De-emphasis: -6dB de-emphasis, 0dB preshoot
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete- EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2- EqualizationPhase3- LinkEqualizationRequest-
             Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr+ BadTLP+ BadDLLP+ Rollover+ Timeout+ AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 0d, ECRCGenCap- ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-ff-fe-81-91-01
    Capabilities: [150 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 3145728ns
        Max no snoop latency: 3145728ns
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
    Kernel modules: rtl8188ee

$ rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ iwlist wlan0 keys

wlan0     2 key sizes : 40, 104bits
          4 keys available :
        [1]: off
        [2]: off
        [3]: off
        [4]: off
          Current Transmit Key: [1]

$ iwlist wlan0 wpakeys

wlan0     2 key sizes : 40, 104bits
          4 keys available :

Error reading wireless keys (SIOCGIWENCODE): Operation not permitted

